# Laravel Inertia error alert is showing even if the form is not submitted

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using Laravel Inertia and Vue. I have the following vue code :

```
<script setup>
const form = reactive({
    prefix: null,
    name: null,
    contact_number: null,
    email_id: null
});

const submit = () => {

    router.post('/create', form)
};
</script>
<div v-if="errors">
    <div class="bg-orange-100 border-l-4 border-orange-500 text-orange-700 p-4" role="alert">
        <p v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the Laravel side, I have the validation:

```
$patient = Patient::create($request->validate(
            [
                'prefix'            => 'required',
                'name'              =>'required|max:50|alpha:ascii',
                'contact_number'    =>'required',
                'email_id'          =>'required|email',
        ]));

        return to_route('patients/index');
```

The issue here is that it is showing the error div if the form is not submitted. I am new to Inertia and I think the if check should validate if there are any error. But it is showing even if there is no errors. Also I would like to show a flash message once the form is submitted. How this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Vue code, you can add a success variable to track if the form submission was successful.

```
<script setup>
const form = reactive({
    prefix: null,
    name: null,
    contact_number: null,
    email_id: null
});

let success = false;

const submit = () => {
    axios.post('/create', form)
        .then(response => {
            // Set success to true and clear the form fields
            success = true;
            form.prefix = null;
            form.name = null;
            form.contact_number = null;
            form.email_id = null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
};
</script>

<div v-if="$page.errors">
    <div class="bg-orange-100 border-l-4 border-orange-500 text-orange-700 p-4" role="alert">
        <p v-for="error in $page.errors">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div v-if="success">
    <div class="bg-green-100 border-l-4 border-green-500 text-green-700 p-4" role="alert">
        <p>Form submitted successfully!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Laravel side, you can use the with() method to pass a flash msg

```
$patient = Patient::create($request->validate([
    'prefix'            => 'required',
    'name'              =>'required|max:50|alpha:ascii',
    'contact_number'    =>'required',
    'email_id'          =>'required|email',
]));

return redirect()->route('patients.index')->with('success', 'Form submitted successfully!');
```

Then show it in view

```
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="bg-green-100 border-l-4 border-green-500 text-green-700 p-4" role="alert">
        <p>{{ session('success') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: when I use `$page.errors` in the if  it is not showing the errors if there is errors.

Comment: In Inertia, if there are validation errors in the form submission, they will be passed to the page as a prop named errors. You can use this prop to check if there are any errors

Comment: <div v-if="Object.keys($page.errors).length">
    <div class="bg-orange-100 border-l-4 border-orange-500 text-orange-700 p-4" role="alert">
        <p v-for="error in $page.errors">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Why don't you try creating an error intentionally to see whether it is your ajax creating problem or it is ur vue code

Comment: working fine when I use `Object.keys(errors).length`. Not sure why it is not working with `v-if`

Comment: it's possible that the v-if directive is not re-evaluating the condition after the errors object is updated. One way to force a re-evaluation of the v-if condition is by using a reactive computed property that depends on the errors object